# Do something after window load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I'm doing a (simple) ajax call on window load:

```
$(window).load(function () {

$.ajax({
url: someUrl,
type: "get",
dataType: "",
success: function(data) {

           ...........
```

How can I do something, for instance a function or event after this ajax proces is finished. The problem is I have to append something to the data recieved by the ajax call. But I can't append on window load because the data is still being processed.

Comment: You see that `success:` callback function?... Callbacks exist for your benefit.

Comment: What do you think the `success` callback is for? ;)

Comment: you can try adding your code in 'complete' instead of 'success'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in the success handler of the ajax call:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: someUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "",
        success: function(data) {
            // do whatever you want with data
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The "success" handler has been deprecated. Use "done" instead. (Similarly, "complete" has been replaced by "always" and "error" by "fail." See Deprecation Notice here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @JackB. `done`, `fail`, and `always` have been there since 1.5 when $.ajax began returning a `promise` object. the handlers passed as options to $.ajax are deprecated, but i don't think we'll ever see them replaced.

Answer (score 3):

You can call that in the **success callback** function of Ajax request

```
success: function(data) {

    myFunction() ;   // If function

    $('#elementID').click() // If you want to trigger a click event
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should execute your request when page is just loaded.

```
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: someUrl,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "",
        success: function(data) {
            // do whatever you want with data
        }
    });
});
```

or you can do:

```
$(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: someUrl,
            type: "get",
            dataType: "",
            complete: function(data) {
                // do whatever you want with data
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the

```
`$(document).ready`
```

So it will be similar to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajax({
url: someUrl,
type: "get",
dataType: "",
success: function(data) {

           //Your code should be here
```

Answer (score 0):

After

```
success: function(data) { 
  for (var ii = 0; ii < data.length; ii++){
    building html here 
  }
  your code here
}
```

you want to enter in your functions within the success function for the ajax call but before the call is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
$.ajax({
 url: someUrl,
 type: "get",
 dataType: "",
 context: document.body
}).done(function() { 
  // do whatever when is done
  onCompleteFunction();
});
```